# How to retrieve and access fields within javascript object literals from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object-literal

Here's a short JS function that attempts to retrieve an object from an array and access its only field:

```
function foo()
{
    var fruitLiteral = {name : "Orange"};
    var myArray = [];
    myArray.push(fruitLiteral);
    console.log(" myArray after push " + myArray);
    var rc = myArray.splice(0,1);
    console.log(" myArray after splice " + myArray);
    console.log(rc.name);
}
```

And the output:

```
 myArray after push [object Object]
 myArray after splice 
 undefined   //wanted to see rc.name, or "Orange" here.
```

The array appears to have been emptied as expected after the splice, but I always get "undefined" for the item retrieved from the splice when it's a literal object. Where's my error?

Comment: The line `console.log(" myArray after push " + myArray);` is *concatenating* the string with the array, and you end up with `myArray after push [object Object]` in the console.  Try `console.log(" myArray after push ", myArray);` and you'll get better information :)

Comment: `rc` is an array.  You can access the first object in it with `rc[0].name`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `fruitLiteral` is still stored as the first element of the `rc` array after splicing so you need to treat it like that.

```
function foo()
{
    var fruitLiteral = {name : "Orange"};
    var myArray = [];
    myArray.push(fruitLiteral);
    console.log(" myArray after push " + myArray);
    var rc = myArray.splice(0,1);
    console.log(" myArray after splice " + myArray);
    console.log(rc[0].name);
}
```

Comment: There's nothing in the array. Splice removed it as it should have.

Comment: Your question was "why I don't see the result or `rc.name` in my console.log"? The answer I gave is correct.

Comment: @swingMan - `rc` is the value returned from `myArray.splice()` which is the first element from `myArray`.

Comment: @holdoc...please explain  why rc is undefined when it should contain the value that was removed from the array via splice().

Comment: `rc` shouldn't be undefined unless `fruitLiteral` is a sparse array.

Comment: @holodoc....I understand...I'm getting an array back, not a literal. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks.

Comment: the answer is absolutely correct - splice can remove more than one elements. method returns removed elements as array, because they can be more than one.